# How to flush opcache?

Tags: magento2, opcache

According to there documentation i needed to use phpinfo() to check for inconsistencies in my php.ini.

I have put it in the index.php because all other files are not accessable from the web. Or give error's like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/magento/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
```

Is there a command like: `magento cache:opcache:reset` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clear PHP OPCache you can just restart PHP - `systemctl restartphp7.0-fpm` (For Ubuntu 16.04)

You can also create an `opcache_clear.php` file with the contents:

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
?>
```

As a side note, to get your phpinfo() to work correctly you need to create the file within the `/path/to/magento/pub/` directory to be able to access it via browser, for example:

Create:

```
/path/to/magento/pub/info.php
```

Access:

```
https://example.com/info.php
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't worked for me.

Comment: From the error you've got it seems to be more a permission issue. Can you ensure that the var/page_cache directory is writable by the web server user/group? 
`chown -R user:www-data /var/www/magento/var` (Example)
`chmod -R 775 user:www-data /var/www/magento/var` (Example)

Comment: I have no idea, i'm a programmer not a system administrator. root@cli:/# chown -R user:www-data /var/www/magento/var
chown: invalid user: 'user:www-data'

Comment: No worries - You can find the user/group of the rest of your files are using by running `ls -la /var/www/magento/` This will output a list of all the files on the CLI that are in that directory we with some extra information. Pay close attention to the values `-rw-r--r--  1 user www-data` (Should be at the far left of the output). If you're able to get a screengrab of the output and update your question with it I can advise further. Otherwise if you can copy/paste a similar output that I've put above I should be able to work it out.

Comment: At my local machine (ubunto) i get: "drwxrwsrwx 10 roger roger   4096 nov 28 15:17 var" but in my docker container called cli i get: "drwxrwsrwx 10 www-data www-data   4096 Nov 28 14:22 var"

Comment: You can try `chown -R roger:roger /var/www/magento/var` on your local and `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento/var` on your Docker

Comment: Hi @RogerGetnoticed, did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: Yes, thanx @Matt Antley. It was a issue with rights in my docker environment. Have marked the answer as a working sollution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on development environment Opcache timestamp validation should always be on to avoid refreshing cache when modifying files

```
opcache.validate_timestamps = On
```